# Symfony and Netbeans PHP

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I have used CRUD to generate actions for an entity. However, I would like to modify the edit action; for instance, a user select 'inactive' represented by 1 for State then they will be shown an error message otherwise they can proceed to updating that row. Within the entity these are the variables state, paypid, startDate, endDate.

This is what the edit action currently looks like.

```
public function editAction($Paypid)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->find($Paypid);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Payrollperiod entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($Paypid);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );        
}
```

This is the payroll period entity

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Payrollperiod
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\PayPeriodRepository")
 *
 * 
 */
class Payrollperiod
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $startdate;

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $enddate;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $state;

/**
 * @var integer
 */
private $paypid;


/**
 * Set startdate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $startdate
 * @return Payrollperiod
 */
public function setStartdate($startdate)
{
    $this->startdate = $startdate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get startdate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getStartdate()
{
    return $this->startdate;
}

/**
 * Set enddate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $enddate
 * @return Payrollperiod
 */
public function setEnddate($enddate)
{
    $this->enddate = $enddate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get enddate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getEnddate()
{
    return $this->enddate;
}

/**
 * Set state
 *
 * @param integer $state
 * @return Payrollperiod
 */
public function setState($state)
{
    $this->state = $state;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get state
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getState()
{
    return $this->state;
}

/**
 * Get paypid
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPaypid()
{
    return $this->paypid;
}

public function setPayid($payid){
    $this->paypid = $payid;
```

}
    /**
     * Render a payrollPeriodID as a string.
     * 
     * @return string
     */

```
public function __toString()
{
 return (string) $this->getstartDate()->format('d-M-y').'/'.$this->getendDate()->format('d-M-y');

}


public function __construct()
{
   $this->PayrollperiodType = new \Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArrayCollection();
}
```

}

Can someone assist me with this issue?

Comment: What is preventing you from editing your controller method to what you need it to do?

Comment: Not sure how to edit it to add an if statement when the state variable is not apart of the function. I tried this.

Comment: public function editAction($Paypid)
    {
       $state="0";
        if ($state=="1"){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')->find($Paypid);

Comment: if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Payrollperiod entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($Paypid);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
        }else{
           throw $this->createNotFoundException('You cannot edit this payroll period.');  
        }
    }

Comment: and that didn't work. asking what otherway could have done it.

Comment: Andrew is it possible to help me out with another question. I would love your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple different ways of handling this. Normally when you generate methods using symfony or doctrine cmds such as `generate:doctrine:crud`, it is boilerplate code to get you going a bit faster and you will update it to meet your needs.

There are a few approaches here, but it depends on the approach and business logic you want. If you are only allowing entities that are currently in an 'Active' state to be edited, then the following will work.

You can create a [custom repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) class and have a method that queries for the entity based on the `$Paypid` provided and `$state = 1`.

```
public function findByPaypidAndActiveState($Paypid)
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod 
                WHERE paypid = :paypid AND state = :state'
        )
        ->setParameter('paypid', $Paypid)
        ->setParameter('state', 0)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Then in the `editAction`, you will query using this method instead of the using `find()`

Another way would be to modify the query in the `editAction` to find by criteria other than the id

```
{
    //....
    $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
        ->findBy(['paypid' => $Paypid, 'state' => 0]);
}
```

From here, you can adjust your error messaging to what you want. The `throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Payrollperiod entity.');` is just boilerplate code by generating crud. This just basically returns a 404 response, which doesn't sound like what you need.

If you are using sessions, you could add a [flash message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#flash-messages) to the session and display it to the user as the error message.

So overall something like this could be a possible solution

```
public function editAction($Paypid)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
        ->findBy(['paypid' => $Paypid, 'state' => 0]);

    if (!$entity) {
        $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        'You cannot edit an inactive Payroll Period'
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('some_route_of_your_choosing');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($Paypid);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );        
}
```

Comment: This gave me an error. Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::findBy() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AgriPayrollSystem\trunk\AgriPayrollSystem\src\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController.php on line 192 and defined in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AgriPayrollSystem\trunk\AgriPayrollSystem\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php

Comment: updated the answer. I missed putting the `findBy()` params as an array

Comment: what does the findby params look like now?

Comment: `$entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod')
        ->findBy(['id' => $Paypid, 'state' => 0]);` Just added `[]` to make the param an array

Comment: sorry, use to it being `id` and not `paypid`. Make sure the keys in `findBy()` match your fields that you query by.

Comment: => do i have to use that. i tried the == and i'm still yielding the same error or if make any changes i get this error Unrecognized field: id. is there another way to maneuver this?

Comment: If your entity property is called `paypid`, the updated query should be like this: `$entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollperiod') ->findBy(['paypid' => $Paypid, 'state' => 0]);`. Switching out `id` for `paypid`

Comment: a different error.

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController::createEditForm() must be an instance of com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity\Payrollperiod, array given, called in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AgriPayrollSystem\trunk\AgriPayrollSystem\src\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController.php on line 204 and defined in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AgriPayrollSystem\trunk\AgriPayrollSystem\src\com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Controller\PayrollperiodController.php

Comment: private function createEditForm(Payrollperiod $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PayrollperiodType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_update', array('Paypid' => $entity->getPaypid())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }

Comment: can you edit your question to provide the Doctrine mappings of your `Payrollperiod` entity. At this point, not sure of any errors. I used similar method for querying for entities using multiple entity properties in my own project with no issues.

Comment: would a relationship mapping cause this error. because i entity that depends on this entity.

Comment: i have added the payroll period entity to the question

Comment: are you doing the property mappings elsewhere for each entity instead of annotations?

Comment: another entity called payroll week depends on the entity payroll period. so the annotations of mapping that relationship are in the payroll week entity

Comment: but the error has passed from the editAction function and move to createEditForm and giving the same error about catchable fatal error. is it a case because the edit Action function added the array params to it

Comment: try changing the `findBy()` method to be `findOneBy()` with the same parameter. `findBy()` returns an array of the Entities. `findOneBy()` should just return a single entity.

Comment: That seems to be fine but gave an error at $this->addFlash. How does this works? Or can it be put another way to output an error message?

Comment: i'm not using a session

Comment: If sessions are not used, there will need to be another method to return an error message to the user. `addFlash()` puts a key => value into the session that can be accessed for display to a user.

Comment: could you provide me with such method

Comment: Answers are not ment to write the code for you. If you are using twig, you can give your can pass what you need to it and display when necessary

Comment: Andrew is it possible to help me out with another question. Would really love your help

Comment: sure. I am still learning symfony as well. Had bunch of similar questions you have had about it this past January for school project.

Comment: Thank you. This is question not sure how to correct it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45089360/symfony-doctrine-query-date-values-against-existing-database-values

Comment: is there a chat or something that can be used instead of comments?

Comment: create a chat room. i'm not getting the option to do so

Comment: Hi Andrew, would for us to have a chat please? Just have an issue that is bothering me and would really like your help.

Comment: Hey Andrew, I'm in need of your help. Get back to me please

Comment: I'm having a dire issue that i need your help with. Please