# Symfony / Doctrine - query date values against existing database values

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, validation, doctrine-orm

I have two entities payroll week and payroll period, want to write a query that checks if the start date and end date entered by the user to the payroll period table is found in the payroll week table which is populated already and update it with that payroll period id in the database. Each classes looks like. This is what I have done thus far regarding the query.

### Payrollperiod Entity:

```
<?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Payrollperiod
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PayrollPeriod")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Payrollperiod
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="payrollperiodid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $payrollperiodid;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="State", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $state;

    public function getPayrollperiodid() {
        return $this->payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function getStartdate() {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    public function getEnddate() {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    public function getState() {
        return $this->state;
    }

    public function setPayrollperiodid($payrollperiodid) {
        $this->payrollperiodid = $payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function setStartdate(\DateTime $startdate) {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }

    public function setEnddate(\DateTime $enddate) {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;
    }

    public function setState($state) {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * Render a payrollPeriodID as a string.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getPayrollperiodid();
    }
}
```

### Payrollweek Entity:

```
<?php

namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Payrollweek
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="PayrollWeek", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_1B4F90669AD94696", columns={"payrollperiodid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Payrollweek
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type("DateTime")
     */
    private $startdate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="endDate", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Type("DateTime")
     * @Assert\Expression("this.getStartDate() < this.getEndDate()",
     *     message="The end date must be after the start date")
     */
    private $enddate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="normalHours", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $normalhours;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numOfDays", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $numofdays;

    /**
     * @var \Payrollperiod
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Payrollperiod")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="payrollperiodid", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $payrollperiodid;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStartdate() {
        return $this->startdate;
    }

    public function getEnddate() {
        return $this->enddate;
    }

    public function getNormalhours() {
        return $this->normalhours;
    }

    public function getNumofdays() {
        return $this->numofdays;
    }

    public function getPayrollperiodid() {
        return $this->payrollperiodid;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function setStartdate(\DateTime $startdate) {
        $this->startdate = $startdate;
    }

    public function setEnddate(\DateTime $enddate) {
        $this->enddate = $enddate;
    }

    public function setNormalhours($normalhours) {
        $this->normalhours = $normalhours;
    }

    public function setNumofdays($numofdays) {
        $this->numofdays = $numofdays;
    }

    public function setPayrollperiodid($payrollperiodid) {
        $this->payrollperiodid = $payrollperiodid;
    }

    /** * Render StartDate and EndDate as a string.
     * * * @return string */

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getStartdate()->format('d-M-y').'/'.$this->getEnddate()->format('d-M-y');

    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->PayrollweekType = new \Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

### Payrollweek Entity Repository:

```
namespace com\twcl\agripayrollBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * PayrollweekRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class PayrollweekRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function payrollPeriodWeek(){
       return $this->EntityManager()->createquery(
               'select startDate and endDate from AcmeDemoBundle:Payrollweek 
               update payrollperiodid' 
               )->getresults() ;
    }
}
```

**CHANGES:**

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Payrollperiod();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $payrollweek=new Payrollweek();
        $payrollperiod=$em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:PayrollPeriod') ->findOneBy(['startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate]);
        if ($payrollperiod) {
        $payrollweek->setPayrollperiod($payrollperiod);
        }
        else{
        $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! Not a valid payroll week');
         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
        }

        $em->persist($payrollweek);
        $em->flush();

        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod_show', array('payrollperiodid' => $entity->getpayrollperiodid())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Comment: This is what I have in the repository thus far public function payrollPeriodWeek(){
       return $this->EntityManager()->createquery(
               'select startDate and endDate from AcmeDemoBundle:Payrollweek 
               update payrollperiodid' 
               )->getresults() ;
        
    }

Comment: Please edit your original question to add that in there, it's too difficult to see the formatting in a comment.

Comment: ok i have edited the original question

Comment: Btw you have a bug in your original code. You have `new \Doctrine\Common\Collection\ArrayCollection();` but Collections is plural. It should be `new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();`

Comment: ok thanks for that one. is this query feasible?

Comment: No - see my answer for help.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to get the PayrollPeriod id, and then update your Payrollweek entity accordingly.  You don't even need any special repository functions.  If you were in a controller it would look like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$payrollweek = // do whatever here to get a Payrollweek entity

$payrollperiod = $em->getRepository('agripayroll:\PayrollPeriod)
    ->findOneBy(['startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate]);

if ($payrollperiod) {
    $payrollweek->setPayrollperiod($payrollperiod);

    $em->persist($payrollweek);
    $em->flush();
}
```

You don't even need to use any custom repository functions, although it wouldn't hurt to put them in there.  I'd also change your `$payrollperiodid` class member to `$payrollperiod` since it refers to the corresponding Payrollperiod entity, and not the individual foreign key integer id.

Comment: ok thanks but what do mean by do whatever here to get a Payrollweek entity. i could just try this in the createAction function?

Comment: And i wouldn't i have to add an error message if the payroll week doesnt exist

Comment: That all depends.  Your initial stated that you wanted to update your Payrollweek with the Payrollperiod id, so I assumed the Payrollweek already existed.  If not, you'll be making a new entity with `$payrollweek = new Payrollweek;`

Comment: the entity does exist but like how it existed already what would go there.

Comment: Not sure if i understand how this will send the payroll period id to the payroll week table in the database. Possible to explain please.

Comment: I have added some changes I made but that wasn't done correctly.

Comment: if i should use it in custom respository what would that function look like.

Comment: I'm kinda lost as i am new to this whole symfony.

Comment: You're on the right track.  The `$em->persist()` and `$em->flush()` calls are what insert into the database.  But in your case you're better off not manually doing this, and doing a form `EntityType` to select it.  Your best bet is to visit the Symfony documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html or go through some tutorials - specifically controllers, forms, and Doctrine.

Comment: The payroll period id should be automically go the payroll week table. But what it doesn't seems to be working like how i want it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the documentation, it sounds like you are trying to run before you walk. Try a bunch of things out.

Comment: Not necessarily on a deadline, this only part giving  problems. I have read the documentation.

Comment: If your `PayrollPeriod` already exists, why not return a list of valid `PayrollPeriod` entities to select from in your form when creating a new PayrollWeek? Probably a bit hard to explain in comments.

Comment: The payroll week is already populated, the info is pulled from this table to see if the payroll week exists when the user enter the payroll period then the payroll week table is updated with the payroll period primary key. The user enters a payroll period over a two weeks basis but in the database its stored for one week.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. If your payroll period already exists that is needed for a PayrollWeek, you can build your form to return PayrollPeriods to select from instead of querying for it after the form is submitted.

In this example, Territory belongs to a Country. So the form will display a list of countries.

```
$builder
    ->add('name', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Territory Name',
    ])
    ->add('abbrev', TextType::class, [
        'label' => 'Territory Abbreviation',
    ])
    ->add('belongingCountry', EntityType::class, [
        'class'         => 'AppBundle:Address\Country',
        'choice_label'  => 'name',
        'label'         => 'Country'
    ]);
```

In your case, if PayrollWeek belongs to PayrollPeriod. You can do the same.

```
$builder
    ->add('payrollperiodid', EntityType::class, [
        'class'         => 'AppBundle:Payrollperiod',
        'choice_label'  => 'startdate'
    ])
```

You will have to mess with the choice_label a bit to format the display of the `\DateTime` as you want.

Comment: This is a great idea but it wouldn't be possible because the user select a two weeks period while in the database it is a one week period. Or i could let start date be one week and end date be the other week and then the payroll week table it is required to be updated with payroll period id

Comment: Then it seems Jason's answer maybe more suitable. Little confused that you are creating a payrollWeek since you are seem to be creating a form for payrollPeriod with this `$entity = new Payrollperiod(); $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);`

Comment: the form is for the payroll period, and data entered goes to the database. but before it goes to the database there's to be a check if that period exits that is found in a payroll week table. I like your idea but what two users enter the same period then the payroll week table will be updated to the current payroll period id

Comment: I'm trying your idea but it doesn't seems to be changing, is it because the formtype was automatically generated from the doctrine?

Comment: Would this be feasible allow the user to select the start and end date from a drop down list, if that period is >a two weeks period then they'll get an error additionally if the user enters a start and end date that already exists then they'll also get an error. Is that too complex?